# How to compare a 1D array to a 2D array

Tags: java

I'd like some assistance on comparing two arrays of different dimensions. I want to check if the single dimensional array is a sub array of the 2 dimensional array. Here's what I tried:

```
public static void compare() {
  int[][] x = {{23, 33, 46, 50, 56}, 
  {3, 8, 65, 34, 90},
  {2, 7, 46, 50, 56}};

  int[] y = {2, 7, 46, 50, 56};

  for (int i = 0; i < x.length - (x.length) + 1; i++) {    
      System.out.println(Arrays.toString(x[2]));
  for (int j = 0; j < y.length - (y.length) + 1; j++) {  
      System.out.println(Arrays.toString(y));
      if (x[2].equals(y)) {
          System.out.println("match");        
      } else {
      System.out.println("no match");
   }
  }
 }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know what exactly you want, but as i can see - you need something like:

```
import java.util.Arrays;

public class Test {
 public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[][] x = {{23, 33, 46, 50, 56},
            {3, 8, 65, 34, 90},
            {2, 7, 46, 50, 56}};

    int[] y = {2, 7, 46, 50, 56};

    for (int[] aX : x) {

        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(x[2]));

        if (Arrays.equals(aX, y)) {
            System.out.println("match");

        } else {
            System.out.println("no match");
        }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I needed a simple answer to what may have been complex to me. The sentinel loop is another tool I could use as an arsenal in programming. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

```
int[][] x = {{23, 33, 46, 50, 56}, 
             {3, 8, 65, 34, 90},
             {2, 7, 46, 50, 56}};

int[] y = {2, 7, 46, 50, 56};

for (int[] i : x) {
  if (Arrays.equals(y, i)) {
    System.out.println("match");
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.*;

public class ArrayMatch {

  public static void main(String[] args){
       int[][] x = {{23, 33, 46, 50, 56}, 
                    {3, 8, 65, 34, 90},
                    {2, 7, 46, 50, 56}};

       int[] y = {2, 7, 46, 50, 56};

       String yArray = Arrays.toString(y);
       boolean match = false;

       for(int i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
           String comparison = Arrays.toString(x[i]);
           if(comparison.equals(yArray)) {
               match = true;

           }

        }
        if(match) {
           System.out.println("Match");
        }
        else
           System.out.println("No match");

        }
      }
```

Here is your output:

```
Match
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    int[][] x = { { 23, 33, 46, 50, 56 }, { 3, 8, 65, 34, 90 }, { 2, 7, 46, 50, 56 } };

    int[] y = { 2, 7, 46, 50, 56 };

    int[] z = x[2].clone();
    int count = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < z.length; i++) {
        if (z[i] != y[i]) {
            System.out.println("Not Match");
            break;
        } else {
            count++;
            if (count == y.length) {
                System.out.println("Match");
                break;
            } else {
                continue;
            }
        }
    }
```

Output is:

```
Match
```

I have copied 2D Array's 2nd element to another array(z[]) because array can be compared to one by one element not directly one array to another array.